# Select a subset of a Data Frame based on timestamp conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, subset

I would like to select a subset of rows from my Data Frame within a specified range of timestamps.

This below is what I have done but it does not seem to be working. I am trying to select the subset of rows that take place between 01/01/2019 01:00 and 01/01/2021 01:00.

Thank you!

```
df.loc[(df['TIMESTAMP'] == "01/01/2019 01:00"): (df['TIMESTAMP'] == "01/01/2021 01:00")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a test DataFrame as:

```
          TIMESTAMP  Amount
0  01/01/2019 00:00   101.0
1  01/01/2019 01:00   102.0
2  01/01/2019 02:00   103.0
3  01/05/2019 01:00   104.0
4  02/02/2020 00:00   105.0
5  01/01/2021 00:00   106.0
6  01/01/2021 01:00   107.0
7  01/01/2021 02:00   108.0
8  01/02/2021 01:00   109.0
```

Note that *TIMESTAMP* column is of *object* type (actually it holds strings).
As you used "/" as separators, I assume US date formatting, i.e. *mm/dd/yyyy*.

The first step is to convert *TIMESTAMP* column to *datetime* type:

```
df.TIMESTAMP = pd.to_datetime(df.TIMESTAMP)
```

If you print *df* now, it will contain:

```
            TIMESTAMP  Amount
0 2019-01-01 00:00:00   101.0
1 2019-01-01 01:00:00   102.0
2 2019-01-01 02:00:00   103.0
3 2019-01-05 01:00:00   104.0
4 2020-02-02 00:00:00   105.0
5 2021-01-01 00:00:00   106.0
6 2021-01-01 01:00:00   107.0
7 2021-01-01 02:00:00   108.0
8 2021-01-02 01:00:00   109.0
```

(this is the way how *Pandas* formats timestamps).

And now, to get rows within your expected datetime range, run:

```
result = df.query('TIMESTAMP.between("2019-01-01 01:00", "2021-01-01 01:00")')
```

Note that although *TIMESTAMP* column is now of *datetime* type,
you can specify datetimes as **strings**.

The result is:

```
            TIMESTAMP  Amount
1 2019-01-01 01:00:00   102.0
2 2019-01-01 02:00:00   103.0
3 2019-01-05 01:00:00   104.0
4 2020-02-02 00:00:00   105.0
5 2021-01-01 00:00:00   106.0
6 2021-01-01 01:00:00   107.0
```